# How does `map` behave that matrix multiplication fails in this example?

Tags: scheme, lisp, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to make a function that does matrix-vector multiplication in scheme. I am confused by the results. Here is my code that defines a function that computes the dot products of two vectors:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
      (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))

(define (dot-product v w)
  (accumulate + 0 (map * v w)))
```

This returns the expected dot product of vectors, like `(list 2 3 4)` and `(list 1 1 1)`. But when I try to compute the product of a matrix and vector with

```
(define (matrix-*-vector m v)
  (map (lambda (x) dot-product v x) m))
```

this function will simply return the original matrix `m`, rather than the expected result. I'm extra confused because I can write this in Wolfram Language just fine and it behaves as expected:

```
myMatrixMult[m_,v_]:=Map[Function[x,Dot[v, x]], m]
```

(I don't think you need to be expert in either language to see the similarities).

What am I misapprehending about the scheme implementation? What needs to be done in order to define matrix-vector multiplication using `map` and `dot-product`?

Comment: Your `accumulate`, though working, could use improvement. Firstly, the `initial` argument in a fold is supposed to be the accumulator; instead you keep passing the original value all the way to the end.  The idea is that `op` gets called with the accumulated value as its left argument, and the new value to be accumulated as the right argument. Secondly, we can do this while also making the procedure tail recursive. `(define accumulate (op accum sequence) (if (null? sequence) accum (accumulate op (op accum (car sequence)) (cdr sequence))))`

Comment: You see how in the non-empty case, we make a tail call back to `(accumulate ...)`.  As the `accum` argument, we pass `(op accum (car sequence))`: the accumulation of the current `accum`, and the next available item.   This function is called "reduce" or a "left fold" and has many uses, not all arithmetical.

Comment: Thanks @Kaz , I will keep that in mind. This implementation was just the one from SICP , unless I made a transcription error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parens in your `lambda`:

```
(lambda (x) dot-product v x)
```

never calls `dot-product`, it just returns `x`.

You need

```
(lambda (x) (dot-product v x))
```

Comment: Haha, of course. Sorry for the silly question.